# How to change keyboard layout in Qt creator (under ubuntu system)?

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator, keyboard-layout

I am using Ubuntu system 14.04, I have Arabic and English layout.

I installed Qt creator 4.2.1 Based on Qt 5.7.1 .

when Qt creator started I couldn't write in English only Arabic !!

**Update:**

I found some thing but it is not a solution: I close Qt creator change layout to English start Qt again and it is work good but changing layout while it is open not responding .

How can I fix that ?

Comment: It is not specific to Qt, but to your desktop environment and window manager. You change the keyboard layout for the entire desktop (not only for a single app like QtCreator). BTW Ubuntu 14.04 is really old, you should use some newer one.

Comment: And the question is not related to programming, so is off-topic here. Should be on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The problem not in my system because i can change the layout using keyboard short cut during working on Qt but it is change every where except Qt .

Comment: I have kind of the same problem my system is fedora 25 and using Qt Creator 4.2.1 based on Qt 5.8.0. My system language and keyboard layout is set to swedish but when typing in qt creator it uses english layout and i cant figure out how to fix it. for example "-" writes "/" in qt and "+" becomes "-"